# Jquery Multi-Select not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm trying to creating a multi-select Drop-down from [Davidstutz](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) I have created as in the tutorial, but it is not working well.

What I did is:

**Attachments**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/multiSelect.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiSelect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Option - 1">Option - 1</option>
    <option value="Option - 2">Option - 2</option>
    <option value="Option - 3">Option - 3</option>
    <option value="Option - 4">Option - 4</option>
    <option value="Option - 5">Option - 5</option>
    <option value="Option - 6">Option - 6</option>
</select>
```

**Java Script Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#multi-select-demo").multiselect({
         buttonText : function(option,select){
             if(option.length == 0){
                 return "select value";
             }
         }
     })
});
```

I have attached all file I can find, not any issues of file attachment.
The main Problem is **dropdown list is not visible** when I click on `button`. The process of behind it is add `open` Class to the Container but I have tested that it is not working.

So, how can I Solve this Problem?

I cant identify either the problem is in `HTML` or `JAVASCRIPT`
I can't identify where the problem is.

All the things I have are same as **David** did in his tutorial, but I can't find out what's going wrong..

**Edit - 1 :**

Guys i have made some changes in my Code, Which is.

```
$(".multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default").click(function(){
    this.addClass("open");
});
```

The mechanism to show dropdown is like this, whenever we click on `Button` javascript is going to add `open` class of css to it. but what i can see is - it is not adding `open` class to it. so, i have try manually to add `open` class to the multi-select container but still it is not working.

can anyone help me on this???

I am really stuck on this problem.. :(

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle ?

Comment: @Lal i am trying that, but in jsfiddle i am not getting the perfect output, will able myb in few time.

Comment: Is there any error in console? before/after clicking on button?

Comment: @Chetan : Nope, i am not getting any Errors, All things are working well, just problem is i cant display Dropdown List, which we have to show onClick of Button.

Comment: I have tried manually to add `open` class to the `div` but still i cant solve this issue..

Comment: Why not create a fiddle instead of displaying in images?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have created fiddle, in it my code is working well, but in pages, it is not.. What can i do now??
Same code in fiddle it worked, but not in my project.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Here it is my fiddle,  [http://jsfiddle.net/Hardy_411/fL1s41qu/]

Comment: some error in JS console? have included jQuery inside your page?

Comment: @Frogmouth : Not any Error found in Console and Yes i have included jQuery in my Page..

Comment: @PraveenKumar : I dont know why, but my HTML Code was not shown as it is, it was transferred into Output, Thats why i have included Images.
Sorry for it..

Answer (score 0):

Add following parameter.

```
buttonContainer: '<div class="btn-grouptest" />'
```